PHP PCRE2 conditional substitution
I'm trying to replace a string in a conditional way using preg_replace in PHP.
The idea is pretty simple and it's working in regex101, but when i try it in PHP it doesn't.
Search pattern:

^([0-9]{3})-?([0-9]{3})-?([0-9]{3})-?([0-9]{3})?$

Replace pattern:

[$1.$2.$3.${4:+$4:000}]

Basically the aim is to format the strings. Valid strings are 9 or 12 digits in groups of 3 digits, if the groups are 4 it's ok, if they are 3 i need to add '000' as final group.
Example - input strings:
009026405
01009556500 (invalid)
226-356-839
009-513-213
000147765000

Expected output:
[009.026.405.000]
01009556500 (unchanged)
[226.356.839.000]
[009.513.213.000]
[000.147.765.000]

PHP source:
<?php
$re = '/^([0-9]{3})-?([0-9]{3})-?([0-9]{3})-?([0-9]{3})?$/mi';
$str = "
009026405
01009556500
226-356-839
009-513-213
000147765000
";
$subst = '[$1.$2.$3.${4:+$4:000}]';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo "text: \n".$str;
echo "\nresult: \n".$result;

Tested on:

PHP 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.23 (cli) (built: Jun 17 2024 13:22:20) ( NTS )
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 (cli) (built: Jun 14 2024 15:52:55) (NTS)

both returning:
[009.026.405.${4:+:000}]
01009556500
[226.356.839.${4:+:000}]
[009.513.213.${4:+:000}]
[000.147.765.${4:+000:000}]

both >7.3 => according to regex101, PCRE2 should be there - about the PCRE2 conditional substitution syntax from regex101 (only available for PCRE2 - PHP>=7.3):


(i didn't find any other doumentation about PCRE2 in PHP)

Please note that i don't need an alternative regex, i need it to work in php as in regex101 website
Thanks.

Not sure if it is still applicable, but I could find this bug notion https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77756 Are you sure it is supported?

You could consider using preg_replace_callback and then check the value of capture group 4

Like @Thefourthbird said :
[2019-03-17 07:12 UTC] requinix@php.net
PHP does not use pcre2_substitute, which is what provides that functionality.
I don't see a need to refactor ext/pcre to support this when preg_replace_callback() exists.

For example like https://3v4l.org/AHtWI

@Thefourthbird: About the bug: i think it's related, and i also think that "PHP does not use pcre2_substitute"; but then why does it work on regex101?
About preg_replace_callback: i cannot use it because i'm setting up dozen of regexes to work on a specific string formats for each country, the best for me would be to set up a search pattern and a replace pattern for each country.

@j.c regex101 probably isn't actually doing the replacement using PHP. It's using PCRE2, and assuming that this is a good representation of PHP 7.3+. But PHP only uses PCRE2 for matching, not for replacing.

preg_replace() can take arrays, so you could use something like $re = ['/-/','/^\d{9}$/m','/^(\d{3})-?(\d{3})-?(\d{3})-?(\d{3})$/m'];, $subst = ['','${0}000','$1.$2.$3.$4'];

@Barmar i guess this is the right answer to the main question, but i can't formerly accept it cause of the "probably" keyword

@bobblebubble thanks, this is an interesting idea, i can avoid customizing tons of code

The linked bug report answers the main question of why the PHP code doesn't work. Do we really need to answer why some random website suggests that it shouold?
